# Is Commerce Server required to connect Dynamics AX to Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore-commerce

As per the subject. I had a client ask whether they needed to install Commerce Server to connect to their retail installation of DAX.

Comment: Ken, it really depends what they would like to do with the connection. Can you please provide some more details?

Comment: So by "it depends" you mean DAX Retial can connect directly without Commerce Server?

Essentially the client doesn't want to pay for or fuss with Commerce Server if they don't have to.

Comment: I am saying that Sitecore Commerce is using a "public" API DAX offers and it depends what you would like to achieve with it you can use Sitecore Commerce or you can build your own connector. Of course if the requirements they have match with the Sitecore Commerce feature set I wouldn't build it my own from scratch. Also learning the API, building the solution, testing and stabilizing, documenting and maintaining your own connector will cost money and the time to market will be much longer meaning the TCO over 3-5 years can be much higher...

Comment: You are only going to want to create your own connector when connecting to a 3rd party commerce system. If you wish to change the connector with SCpbAX, just use pipeline overrides. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You have to install commerce server to create an edge catalog between the commerce site and AX. Your website calls commerce runtime services for catalog information and real time services for customer and order information.

Then AX syncs products with the edge catalog via the AX real time services.

http://commercesdn.sitecore.net/SCpbMD81/SitecoreCommerceMicrosoftDynamics/en-us/Concepts/c_AX_CommerceServerCatalogEdgeCatalog.html

Comment: @KenGray - you're new here, welcome :-)   Contributors to this site much prefer you use the built in vote mechanics to indicate if an answer was useful to you and provided you with sufficient detail. As a consequence, you don't need to express gratitude in comments on every answer either - this doesn't really add SEO value to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore Commerce is using a "public" API DAX offers and it depends what you would like to achieve with it you can use Sitecore Commerce or you can build your own connector.

Of course if the requirements they have match with the Sitecore Commerce feature set I wouldn't build it my own from scratch. Also learning the API, building the solution, testing and stabilizing, documenting and maintaining your own connector will cost money and the time to market will be much longer meaning the TCO over 3-5 years can be much higher...